# Has this generalization of gambler's ruin been studied?

Tags: stochastic-processes, gambling

I looked around to see if I could find a duplicate of this question and I found this [Probability of Gambler's Ruin with Unequal Gain/Loss](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207359/probability-of-gamblers-ruin-with-unequal-gain-loss)

which is very close but lacking in the main generalization aspect I had in mind.

Suppose a gambler has initial fortune $M > 0$, and win probability $p$ for each round with gain $a > 0$ if the round is won and loss $b > 0$ otherwise, where $M,a,b$ can be any positive reals without any restrictions such $a,b,M \in {\mathbb N}$ which was assumed in the linked question and the answer and paper that treats it.

As usual, the gambler is ruined (and the game stops) the first round $t$ when their current fortune $X_t$ becomes $\leq 0$.

The probability of eventual ruin should still be $1$ if and only if the expected winnings of each round is non-positive. But other than that, I wonder if there can be any non-trivial progress to express/compute probability of eventual ruin (e.g. perhaps similar to the paper in the linked question, but in any event better/more insightful than naïve series where each variable $X_t$ is treated individually) as a function of general $M,a,b$. The main obstacle is the chaotic nature of the sign of $M + wa - (t -w)b$ when $w \leq t$ are positive integers but $M,a,b$ might not even be linearly dependent over the rationals.

Comment: Yes. Generally, if $S_0=M\ge 0$ and $S_n=S_0+\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ for i.i.d. $X_i$ with $E(X)>0$, then probability of ruin ($S_t<0$) is
$$P(Ruin)=\frac{\exp(-\tau M)}{E(\exp(\tau\Delta))}<\exp(-\tau M)$$
where $\tau$ is a positive solution to $E(\exp(-\tau X))=1$ and $\Delta>0$ is the amount by which the player gets ruined. In your scenario, $\Delta\le b$ which yields an (easy) lower bound for $P(Ruin)$.