# A gambler's ruin problem with winning size of 3

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I play a game where I have a $25$% chance of winning \$ $3$ and a $75$% chance of losing \$ $1$. Currently, I have \$ $5000$. I will stop playing once I either earn \$ $20000$ or lose all of my \$ $5000$. When I stop, what is the probability of having lost all of my \$ $5000$?

The winning is not $1$, so I think I cannot use the formula $$\frac{1-(q/p)^i}{1-(q/p)^N}$$ where $N$ is the wining amount of money, i.e. \$ $5000$ and $i$ is the money we start with.

What should be changed in this formula to calculate the probability of bankruptcy?

Comment: You might first consider your expected bankroll after each step.

Comment: The same questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/207359/1231520, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1590831/1231520,  for the general case see the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4203

Comment: @Amir: Given the particular values for this problem, don't you think it can be handled more simply as a special case ?

Comment: @Amir I don't see there's any upper limit in those. That is, there's only ruin, no (finite) victory.

Comment: @ploosu2 you may see that the general case is an older problem; for example, see Feller (1968, Vol.1, Section XIV.8). The above paper derived an explicit formula for the case with $W \to \infty$, but it also discussed the general case with $W < \infty $ in introduction, please see Eq. (6).

Comment: @Amir The procedure given in that paper, supposedly covering "the general case", *isn't applicable* to the problem posed here, and the questions cited as duplicates aren't.  In  the problem treated by the paper, *the player continues betting* as long as he or she has not been ruined, and the expected gain on each turn is *strictly positive*.  As a consequence the game will continue indefinitely with strictly positive probability.   Those assumptions are false for the problem posed here.  I have voted to reopen the question.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera thanks for the feedback.I did not vote to close the question, and upvoted the question to allow other members to present *specialized and different* solutions for *this simple case*  (the distribution takes two values, with zero mean). Please read my response above. The general case is **a very old problem**; see Feller (1968, Vol.1, Section XIV.8). The above paper derived an explicit formula for the general case where $W \to \infty$, but discussed the general case with $W<∞$ in introduction (see (6)). Also, please read the answer in the other similar question.

Comment: @Amir My apologies for misunderstanding your comments.  I did read the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207359/probability-of-gamblers-ruin-with-unequal-gain-loss) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590831/has-this-generalization-of-gamblers-ruin-been-studied),  but I don't consider them relevant to this one for the reasons given in my previous comment.

Comment: I'm also aware that the methods for solving the general case of this particular problem have been known for a long time, but a proper answer to the question should  (in my opinion) show how one of those general methods can be applied to solve this particular problem, just as ploosu2 and torontohrb  have done in their answers (although I believe the latter answer is not quite right).

Comment: @trueblueanil  I could not prove that your method in your answer is correct as the roots of $p_X(z)=1$ determine the ruin probability (see (6) in the above paper), but I think it can be proven that as $N, i \to \infty$ (they are sufficiently large) and $\mathbb E (X)=0$, which is the case here, your argument works, that is, the ruin probability tends to the limit of $\frac{N-i}{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_j$ be the probability of bankruptcy when starting with initial capital $j$ dollars. We have the recursion

$$
p_j = \frac{3}{4}p_{j-1} + \frac{1}{4}p_{j+3}
$$

if $1\leq j \leq M-3$ and the conditions $p_0 = 1$ and $p_M=0$ (denoting $M=20000$). Re-indexing ($k=j+3$) and transforming the recurrence equation a bit we have

$$
p_k = 4p_{k-3} - 3p_{k-4}
$$

This is a linear homogenous recurrence with characteristic polynomial $z^4-4z+3$, which has roots $1$ (a double root) and $-1\pm i \sqrt{2}$. Let's denote $w = -1+i\sqrt{2} = \sqrt3 e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta = \pi - \arctan \sqrt2 \approx 2.186276$. So the solution is given

$$
p_k = c_1 + c_2k + c_3w^k+c_4 \bar w  ^k
$$

*(Notice that in reality the recurrence doesn't hold anymore when $k>M$ and the solution will give nonsense after that but we don't care since we're only interested in the region $k\in \{0,\dots, M\}$. Same thing also happens for the usual gambler's ruin)*

We just have to solve these coefficients.

From $p_0=1$ we get $c_1 + c_3 + c_4 = 1$. And from $p_M=p_{M+1}=p_{M+2} = 0$ we get three equations and we're ready to solve them. Given $M$, we can solve them with computer (the numbers become large so it might become hard). But it is quite apparent that as $M$ is large $c_1$ is close to $1$ and $c_2$ close to $-\frac{1}{M}$ and the oscillatory terms don't contribute that much (i.e. $c_3$ and $c_4$ are small (very small, as them multiplied by $w^k$ must go to $0$)). So the solution is very approximately linear, in the case $k=5000, M=20000$ very close to $p_k = 0.75$.

For example for $M=30$ the solution looks like this (usual gambler's ruin with $p=\frac{1}{4}$ and the linear solution for reference)

[image: graph of the bankcruptcy probabilities for M=30]

**Here's one calculation I got trying to solve the system by hand:**

After some manipulation (just using the equations for $k=0,M,M+1$) we arrive to

$$
\left(1-(M+1)w^M+Mw^{M+1}\right)c_3 + \left(1-(M+1)\bar w^M+M\bar w^{M+1}\right)c_4 = 1
$$

Also, we kind of know that $c_4 = \bar c_3$ and $c_1, c_2$ are real.

Could also solve it by computer algebraically but the solution doesn't look very nice. Here's my Sage-code (also the one I used for solving numerically):

```
def solveIt(k, M):
    w1 = CDF(-1+sqrt(2)*i)
    w2 = CDF(-1-sqrt(2)*i)
    A = matrix(CDF, [[1,k,w1^k,w2^k] for k in [0, M,M+1,M+2] ])
    cVec = A.solve_right(vector([1,0,0,0]))
    show(cVec)
    c1,c2,c3,c4 = list(cVec)
    print ( (1-(M+1)*w1**M+M*w1**(M+1))*c3 )
    ret = c1+c2*k+c3*w1**k+c4*w2**k
    return ret.real()

def solveCs():
    w1 = -1+sqrt(2)*i
    w2 = -1-sqrt(2)*i
    M, y1, y2 = var('M, y1, y2') #y1 = w^M, y2 = bar(w)^M
    A = matrix([[1,0,1,1], [1,M,y1,y2], [1,M+1,w1*y1,w2*y2], [1,M+2,w1**2*y1,w2**2*y2]])
    sol = A^(-1)*vector([1,0,0,0])
    for c in sol:
        show(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have little knowledge of random walks,
but it strikes me that if we look at it play by play, the expected gain for success $=\frac14\cdot 3 = \frac34$\$ and the expected loss for failiure $=\frac34\cdot1 = \frac34$\$

In other words, the expected gain/loss is linear, thus by the usual formula,

P(go bankrupt) = $\dfrac{(20000-5000)}{20000} = 0.75$

Comment: You may check the related question I just asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4888386/1231520.

Answer (score 0):

If you know Martingale, this is easy to solve. Let $X_n$ be the cumulative money you have at step $n$. Define stopping time as $T=inf\{n\ge 1: X_n=0\;or\; X_n=20,000\}$. Since $E[X_{n+1}|X_n]=X_n$, $\{X_n\}$ is a Martingale. Since the stopping time is bounded, we have $E[X_T]=X_0$. Now let $r$ be the ruin probability and set up the equation as
$$X_0=5000=E[X_T]=(r)(0)+(1-r)(20000)$$
It is easy to see that $r=3/4$.
Put this in plain English: This is a fair game, which means that the expected money you have should be 5,000 all the time. By the time the game stops, the expectation should be 5,000, which is also $(r)(0)+(1-r)(20000)$.

BTW, if you are learning stochastic processes. One of the best books on this subject you should take a look at is A First Look at Stochastic Processes by Rosenthal.

Comment: But couldn't we also end up at $X_n=20001$ or $X_n=20002$?

Comment: Yes. Here is a rigorous explanation: Considering the random walk with $p=1/4$, we know that $f_{5000,0}=1$, which means that $E[T]<\infty$. Let $X_n=5000+Z_1 +\dots +Z_n$, where $Z_i$ is bet $i$. Since $E[Z_i]=0$, we have $E[X_T]=5000+0\cdot E[T]=5000$ by Wald's Theorem.

Comment: I mean in the definition of $T$. If we are on $X=1999$ and the next $Z=3$, we don't stop?

Comment: @toronto hrb I think ploosu2's point is that the definition of your stopping time should be
$$T\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\inf\big\{\,n\ge1\,:\,X_n\in\{0,20000,20001,20002\}\big\}\  .$$
I agree. Your equation then becomes $$5000=\big(1-r-q_{20001}-q_{20002}\big)20000+q_{20001}20001+q_{20002}20002\ ,$$ giving$$r=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{q_{20001}+2q_{20002}}{20000}\ ,$$where $\ q_i=\Bbb{P}\big(X_T=i\big)\ .$ Since $\ q_{20001}\ $ and $\ q_{20002}\ $ are both strictly positive, the ruin probability $\ r\ $ is a little larger than $\ 0.75\  .$

Comment: You can obtain an  approximation to $\ r\ $ by using the observation that $\ q_{20000}, q_{20001}\ $ and $\ q_{20002}\ $ must all be very close to the same value, $\ \frac{1-r}{3}\ .$ This gives $\ r\approx\frac{15001}{20001}\approx0.750012\ .$ The closest $9$-significant digit approximation to the exact value is $\ 0.750008333\ .$