# Asymptotic Gambler's Ruin Probability with Unequal Gain/Loss with Zero-Mean Payoff Distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

The gambler's ruin problem with unequal gain/loss with a payoff distribution whose support is a finite subset of $\mathbb Z$ is an old problem; for example, see Feller (1968, Vol.1, Section XIV.8) and this old MSE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/207359/1231520). The simple case of the problem where the payoff distribution takes $-1$ and $1$ with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$, has been studied in many introductory text books (it can be easily adjusted for the case the payoff distribution takes $-1$, $1$, and $0$ with probabilities $p$, $q$, and $1-p-q>0$). The ruin probability for the general case is a linear combination of the roots of the following equation:

$$P_X(z)=1 \Leftrightarrow M_X(t)=1$$

where $P_X(z)=\mathbb E(z^X)$ and $M_X(t)=\mathbb E(e^{tX})$ are the generating function and moment generating function of $X$, respectively.

Inspired by the heuristic method used in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4887175/1231520), I guess if $\mathbb E(X)=0$ and the range of $X$ is fixed, we have

$$\color{blue}{\lim_{N,M \to \infty} \mathbb P_\text{ruin}(M,N)= \lim_{N,M \to \infty} \frac{N-M}{N}}. $$

Here, $M$ is the gambler's initial wealth, and he is ruined if he loses all of it. If the gambler’s fortune exceeds $N>M$, the gambler wins and his opponent or the casino is ruined.

For any $M$ and $N$, the relation holds for the simple case of the problem described earlier. This is also supported by the method used to adjust the simple case of the problem for the case where $0$ payoff appears with non-zero probability.

The above can be **a useful result** (if it is proven generally), because **in practice** the initial moneys of the players ($M$ and $N-M$) can be relatively large compared to the payoff $X$ gained in each round of the game, and the condition $\mathbb E(X)=0$ is somehow shows that the game is balanced and fair.

I am seeking a counterexample, or a rigorous proof for the above conjecture. This can be first studied for the simple payoff distribution that takes two integer values $-r$ and $k$ with probabilities $\frac{k}{r+k}$ and $\frac{r}{r+k}$.

Comment: If the expected bankroll stays constant with each bet (i.e. the payoffs are fair based on the probabilities) then this is a consequence of the optional stopping theorem (approximately after allowing for the complication that the variable amounts in the bets and payoffs could mean that $0$ and $N$ may not be hit exactly).

Comment: @Henry do you mean that this holds for any values of $M,N$ considering that the gambler's wealth is a martingale? Is it a formal proof? I also cannot understand the part of your comment in the parenthese.

Comment: @Amir: Thanks, learning a bit about  random walks  through you interest. $5000\div \frac34$ is not a whole number of steps, so some approximation, I guess.

Comment: @Henry Could you also check the discussions made after the following answer that used the same idea of martingales for a distribution taking two values: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4887246/1231520

Comment: @Amir That answer looks reasonable at first glance and its comments raise the issue that you may not stop at exactly $0$ and $N$.  My first parentheses are saying that with a fair game you have a martingale.

Comment: @Henry I think the issue of that answer is solved in the answer just given below by lonza leggiera, which proves the conjecture holds as $N \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be proved by appealing to the [optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem) for martingales. If $\ X_r\ $ is the amount the player wins in round $\ r\ ,$
$$
\color{blue}{X_r\in[-a,b\,]}
$$
with probability $1$, where $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ are positive, $\ \mathbb{E}\big(X_r\big)=0\ ,$ and $\ \mathbb{E}\big(\big|X_r\big|
\big)>0\ ,$ then the player's wealth $\ W_r\ $ after round $\ r\ $ is given by $\ W_0=M\ $ and
$$
W_r=M+\sum_{i=1}^rX_i
$$
for $\ r\ge1\ ,$ provided the process hasn't terminated. Since
\begin{align}
\Bbb{E}\big(W_{r+1}\,\big|\,W_1,W_2,\dots,W_r\,\big)&=\Bbb{E}\big(W_r+X_{r+1}\,\big|\,W_1,W_2,\dots,W_r\,\big)\\
&=W_r\ ,
\end{align}
the process $\ \big\{W_r\big\}\ $ is a [martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)).  The process stops on round $\ T\ ,$ given by
$$
T=\inf\big\{\,r\ge1\,\big|\,W_t\le0\ \text{ or }\ W_t\ge N\,\big\}\ .
$$
The random variable $\ T\ $ is a [stopping time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time) for $\ \big\{W_r\big\}\ ,$ and is finite with probability $1$ (will be proved later).  Therefore, the optional stopping theorem tells us that
$$
\Bbb{E}\big(W_T\big)=\Bbb{E}\big(W_0\big)=M\ .
$$
Since $\ 0<W_{T-1}<N\ $ and $\ W_T=W_{T-1}+X_T\ ,$ then $\ -a<W_T<N+b\ $ with probability $1,$ and since $\ W_T\le0\ $ or $\ W_T\ge N\ ,$ then $\ W_T\in(-a,0]\cup[N,N+b)\ $ with probability $1$. Thus if $\ G\ $ is the cumulative distribution function of $\ W_T\ ,$ then
\begin{align}
M&=\Bbb{E}\big(W_T\big)\\
&=\int_{-a}^0w\,dG(w)+\int_N^{N+b}w\,dG(w)\\
&=\int_{-a}^0w\,dG(w)+\int_N^{N+b}(w-N)\,dG(w)+N\int_N^{N+b}\,dG(w)\\
&=\int_{-a}^0w\,dG(w)+\int_N^{N+b}(w-N)\,dG(w)\\
&\hspace{2em}+N\,\Bbb{P}\big(N\le W_T<N+b\big)\ .
\end{align}
Now $\ -a\le\int_\limits{-a}^{\hspace{0.8em}0}w\,dG(w)<0\ ,$$\ 0\le\int_\limits{N}^{\hspace{0.8em}N+b}(w-N)\,dG(w)\le b\ ,$ and $\ \Bbb{P}\big(N\le W_T<N+b\big)=1-P_{\text{ruin}}\ ,$ where  $ P_{\text{ruin}} $ is the probability of the player's ruin. Therefore we can write the above equation as:
$$
M=I_1+I_2+\left (1-P_{\text{ruin}} \right)N\ ,
$$
where $\ \big|I_1+I_2\big|\le\max(a,b)\ ,$ or
$$
P_{\text{ruin}}-\frac{N-M}{N}=\frac{I_1+I_2}{N}\ ,
$$
from which it follows that
$$
\color{blue}{\left|\,P_{\text{ruin}}-\frac{N-M}{N}\right|<\epsilon}
$$
whenever $\color{blue}{\ N>\frac{\max(a,b)}{\epsilon}\ }.$

**Proof that** $\ T\ $ **is almost surely finite**

By definition,
\begin{align}
\{\ T=\infty\,\}&=\bigcap_{t=1}^\infty\big\{\,0<W_t<N\,\big\}\\
&=\bigcap_{t=1}^\infty\left\{\,{-}M<
\sum_{i=1}^t X_i<N-M\,\right\}\\
&\subseteq\left\{\,{-}M<
\sum_{i=1}^t X_i<N-M\,\right\}
\end{align}
for all $\ t\ .$ Therefore
$$
\Bbb{P}(T=\infty)\le \Bbb{P}\left({-}M<
\sum_{i=1}^t X_i<N-M\,\right)\tag{1}\label{e1}
$$
for all $\ t\ .$ The condition $\ \mathbb{E}\big(\big|X_r\big|
\big)>0\ $ guarantees that the random variables $\ X_r\ $ have positive variance $\ \sigma\ ,$ say.  By the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), therefore, the distributions $\ F_n\ ,$ say, of the random variables
$$
\frac{\sum_\limits{i=1}^nX_i}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}
$$
converge pointwise to the standard normal distribution as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ .$  Let $\ \delta>0\ $  be such that
$$
\mathcal{N}(0,1;\delta)-\mathcal{N}(0,1;{-}\delta)<\frac{\epsilon}{3}\ ,
$$
and $\ L\ $ such that
\begin{align}
\big|F_n({-}\delta)-\mathcal{N}(0,1;{-}\delta)\big|&<\frac{\epsilon}{3}
\ \text{ and }\\
\big|F_n(\delta)-\mathcal{N}(0,1;\delta)\big|&<\frac{\epsilon}{3}
\end{align}
for all $\ n\ge L\ .$ Let
$$
t\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\max\left(L,\left\lceil\left(\frac{M}{\sigma\delta}\right)^2\right\rceil, \left\lceil\left(\frac{N-M}{\sigma\delta}\right)^2\right\rceil\right)\ .
$$
Then $\ \frac{M}{\sigma \sqrt{t}}<\delta,  \frac{N-M}{\sigma \sqrt{t}}<\delta \ ,$ and
\begin{align}
\Bbb{P}\left({-}M<
\sum_{i=1}^t X_i<N-M\,\right)&=\Bbb{P}\left(\frac{{-}M}{\sigma \sqrt{t}}<
\frac{\sum_\limits{i=1}^t X_i}{\sigma \sqrt{t}}<\frac{N-M}{\sigma \sqrt{t}}\,\right)\\
&\le\Bbb{P}\left({-}\delta\le
\frac{\sum_\limits{i=1}^t X_i}{\sigma \sqrt{t}}<\delta\,\right)\\
&=F_t(\delta)-F_t({-}\delta)\\
&=F_t(\delta)-\mathcal{N}(0,1;\delta)\\
&\hspace{1em}+\mathcal{N}(0,1;{-}\delta)-F_t({-}\delta)\\
&\hspace{1em}+\mathcal{N}(0,1;\delta)-\mathcal{N}(0,1;{-}\delta)\\
&<\epsilon\ .
\end{align}
Inequality (\ref{e1}) thus gives
$$
\Bbb{P}(T=\infty)\le\epsilon\ ,
$$
and since $\ \epsilon\ $ can be an arbitrary positive real number, it follows that $\ \Bbb{P}(T=\infty)=0\ .$

Comment: Thank you Lonza for the nice answer, which not only shows that the conjecture holds under less conditions (i.e., $N \to \infty$ and for any payoff distribution with finite support), but also indicates how to measure the error of approximation of the ruin probability with $\frac{N-M}{N}$.

Comment: 1- Could you clarify why $T$ is finite with probability 1 (which is required to use the optional stopping theorem)? 2- Do you think providing a proof based on the old approach used in Feller (1968) is possible?

Comment: When using CLT, I think we need $n^{\frac{1}{2}}$ instead of $n^{\frac{3}{2}}$.

Comment: Yes.  Thank you for picking up the error. Now fixed.  There are probably slicker ways of proving this, but appeal to the CLT was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Thank you again! Could we also use $|X_{\min(i,T)}| \le \min(a,b)$ instead of a.s. finiteness of $T$ as a condition that allows us to use the optional stopping theorem (which is the third condition given in the Wikipedia)? The issue is that the variance of $X_r$ can be zero in that case, which is not reasonable.

Comment: For the notation I've used in my answer, Wikipedia's condition (c) becomes $\big|\color{red}{W}_{\min(i,T)}\big|$ is almost surely bounded, which is guaranteed under the assumptions made.  The random variable $X_r$ can have zero variance only if it's $0$ almost surely, in which case $\ P_\text{ruin}=0\ .$ The condition $\ \big|W_{\min(i,T)}\big|\ $ bounded a.s. could only be non-trivially applicable when the distribution of $\ X_r\ $ didn't have finite support.  I'm guessing that even in that case it will be true that $\ T\ $ will still be almost surely finite and the result will still hold.

Comment: It would be very interesting if that result can be proven. In that case, the finite variance is used to prove the convergence of ruin probability ($a,b$ cannot be used anymore), or you guess it holds for any zero-mean distribution? A counterexample may be constructed using martingales literature.